# intelliJ, Android Studio - Javadoc comment auto complete

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am transitioning from eclipse to android studio and wondering how I can enable the auto-complete in javadoc comments. For example in eclipse, in javadoc comments if we type `HttpRe` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, it gives the option of `{@link HttpRequest}`  tag or if we type `<cod` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, it is changed to `<code></code>`.

How can I enable this in android studio?

Answer (score 1):

I am coming from Eclipse, too. Auto-completion is enabled by default, but you have to understand these IntelliJ concepts:

**Code Completion**: Type `<code>` and IntelliJ will autocomplete it to`<code></code>`.

**Class Name Completion**: Type `HttpRe` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to complete it to `HttpRequest`. You can also type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> twice, which is what I do.

**Live Template**: Select `HttpRequest` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>to surround it with `{@link...}`